# THE Procedure entry point OCIstmtgetNextresult could not be located in the dynamic link library oci.dll

Tags: php, oracle, dll, xampp, oracle-call-interface

I just installed xampp v3.2.2 on my pc.
I want to create connection string to oracle using php.
when i start Apache on xampp, always show popup window "OCI.DLL IS MISSING FROM your computer".
I've been download oci.dll from http://www.dll-found.com/download/o/oci.dll and place it inside C/windows/SysWOW64

but, when i start apache on xampp again, show popup window "THE Procedure entry point OCIstmtgetNextresult could not be located in the dynamic link library oci.dll"
[like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9aME.png)

what should i do?
thanks

Answer (score 11):

You need to download the whole of the Oracle Instant client that matches your OS and its bitness, e.g. 12.1.0.2 for 64 bit for example, from the Oracle website (you may need to create a free account).

Uncompress the contents in the folder of your choice.
Add the path to this folder to your PATH environment variable.

Copy *all* the files within the main directory to your Apache/bin folder, the one that contains httpd.exe
Note that a subset of these files may be copied, but I can't remember which exactly. You may work by elimination eventually, once you have the system to work.

Configure php.ini (the one inside Apache) to activate this module:

```
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
```

Restart Apache. It should work.

A similar job may be done for php in cli mode.
In this case, copy the files from the Oracle Instant Client into the php folder, the one that contains php.exe, *not* the ext/ folder.
Similarly, edit php.ini for cli.
Verify that module oci8 gets loaded by issuing a:

```
php -m
```

command from a console.
Remember that your should reopen the console to load the latest PATH variable.

Comment: I've found the minimal set of files to be copied across for it to work: oci.dll, oraociei12.dll and oraons.dll

Answer (score 2):

this is a problem with the x64 Edition of PHP 5.6.2x and Oracle Instant Client....i got the same error, i changed to x86

Answer (score 2):

#### What I did first-

- My PC- `Windows 10 64 bit`
- Downloaded  `XAMPP Version 8.0.6` (x64 bit)
- Downloaded  Oracle Instant Client for 64-bit(`instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.11.0.0.0dbru.zip`)
- Added path `"C:\instantclient_19_11"` in system variable
- Downloaded `"8.0 Thread Safe (TS) x64"` (`oci8 3.0.1`). the extracted it and added all files with extension  `.dll`, `.pdb`, `pd`  in  `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- After that, I configured `php.ini` (uncommented the extension -`"extension=php_oci8_12c.dll"`)

After doing all of this I was getting the same kind of error.

#### How I solved-

I found that ***`8.0 Thread Safe (TS) x64`*** is causing the problem. So I decided to use `oci8 x86` bit instead.

- For `oci8 x86` bit we need XAMPP(`xampp-portable-win32-7.3.2-0-VC15-installer.exe`) of `Windows 32-bit`. (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/7.3.2/)
- We also need `Oracle Instant Client` for `Windows 32-bit`. (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html), extracted the folder and placed it in the c drive.(add path `"C:\instantclient_19_11"` in system variable, if you haven't)
- XAMPP of Windows 32-bit is having PHP Version `7.3.2.` so I downloaded `7.3 Thread Safe (TS) x86` (https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows), extracted it and replaced the files in `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Lastly, I configured `php.ini` (uncommented the extension -`"extension=php_oci8_12c.dll"`)

Then I was able to successfully connect my oracle database.